# How to use ActionResult return null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionresult

i am using ajax call to save data and print the receipt.
My ajax call is

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Payments/AddPayment",
    data: frm,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (objData) {
        //ResetFormData();

        if (objData.AMENDEDBY == "") {
            strMsg = "Added Sucessfully";
        }
        else {
            strMsg = "Updated Sucessfully";
        }
        AlertData(strMsg, "Payments", "success");

        window.location.assign("/Report/PrintReport?objData=" + objData.REFNO);
    }

});
```

Data saved accurately and after that i want to take print of the saved data.
i am using

```
window.location.assign("/Report/PrintReport?objData=" + objData.REFNO);
```

my Controller code for pritn crystal report is

```
     public ActionResult PrintReport(string objData)
    {
        try
        { 
        //Report Object
        ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
        rd.Load(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Reports/Accounts"), "CrystalReport1.rpt"));
        rd.RecordSelectionFormula = "{TBL_ACC_VOUCHERS_MASTER.REFNO}='" + objData + "'";

        //Report Connection object
        ReportRepo objReport = new ReportRepo();
        rd = objReport.GetReportConnections(rd);

        //Print Report Direct to Default Printer
        PrintDocument pdoc = new PrintDocument();
        string PrinterName = pdoc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;
        rd.PrintOptions.PrinterName = PrinterName;
        rd.PrintToPrinter(1, true, 0, 0);
        return new EmptyResult();
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Report printed successfully but as return i am getting default view with reset values. I want to get the same view without any change.

i also used

```
return Redirect(HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri);
```

but same result

Comment: try return RedirectToAction("your action name",new { objData="your recieved value"});

Comment: i got the same result

Comment: so, issue resolved ?

Comment: no, page is resetting its to default view